# how to make twitter bootstrap navbar fixed width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

How can I make twitter bootstrap navbar fixed width, while keeping it centered?

I've tried adding a width parameter in .navbar, but then the navbar is misaligned.

```
.navbar {
overflow: visible;
margin-bottom: 20px;
color: #956362;
*position: relative;
*z-index: 2;
width: 650px; 
}
```

I also tried

```
<div class="span6 offset3">
```

but this also makes it misaligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround it with a div.
Give that div a fixed width.

Something like:

```
<div class="navbar-outer">
  <div class="navbar">
     <!--here goes the rest of the code-->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-outer {
  width:500px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also added margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto and got it to work!